# how to pop-open a chatbot window on clicking a button/icon using a javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a chatbot, using a power virtual agent, right now i've hosted it on local server.

I want to embed it in my website, so what exactly i want to have is something like button/icon hovering on right bottom side of website.

And on clicking it, it should pop opens a chat bot window over the website. How should i proceed to do this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a form:

```
 //index.html
<div class="chat-popup" id="myForm">
  <form class="form-container">
    <h1>Chat bot</h1>

    <label for="msg"><b>Message</b></label>
    <textarea placeholder="Type your message.." name="msg" required></textarea>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Send</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

and two functions - one to pop up the form for data entry by the user and another to close it:

```
//script.js
function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}
```

To pin your button to the bottom right of the page, have some code like this as part of your CSS file - style the rest of the form as you please:

```
//style.css
.open-button {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 23px;
  right: 28px;
  width: 280px;
}

.form-popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 9;
}
```